# NSSliderをマトリックスに設定したが表示がおかしいです。

Tags: macos, xcode7

NSSliderをマトリックスに設定してコンパイルしました。
しかし表示がおかしいです。

インターフェースビルダーでNSSliderをVerticalで作成したのに、
実行してみると、なぜかHorizontalになってしまいます。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
インターフェースビルダーでの表示はVerticalです。

どうしたら正しい表示になりますか?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

現象の再現を確認しました。こちらが試した方法は。

1. Vetrical Sliderを一つ置いて、Embed→Matrix　columnを２に　：　水平スライダー化
2. Vertical Sliderを２つ置いて、両方を選択して Embed→Matrix 　：　垂直スライダーのまま

どちらの場合も、Sliderのインスタンスの`vertical`プロパティは`YES`のままでした。
尚、2.の方法の場合はそこから更に、行・列を増やしても垂直が維持されましたので、結果論的な手順になりますが、スライダーを複数配置してからそれらを選んでマトリックス化する方が不本意な現象に悩まされずに済みそうです。

蛇足ですが、水平スクローラーと垂直スクローラーをそれぞれ配置して、マトリックス化しても結果は水平スクローラーとして表示されてしまったので、マトリックス化は垂直または水平スクローラー同士でのみ行えると考えた方が良さそうです。

Comment: 回答していただきありがとうございます。